# Last 5 comments for x articles query with mysql

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, distinct

I have 3 tables:

-categories (-categories not important)

**-articles**

**-comments**

---

example:

**-articles**
I have 10000+ articles

**-comments**
I have 10000+ comments for random -articles

---

-I'm trying to show "**last 5 comments**"

OF **articles.article_id s**= in(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

WITH **order by comments.comment_id desc**

WITH categories.category_id,categories.category_name

**-SQL-QUERY-1:**

```
select 
comments.comment_id,comments.comment_title,comments.article_id, 
articles.article_id,articles.article_title,articles.category_id, 
categories.category_id,categories.category_name from comments 
left join (articles,categories) on (comments.article_id=articles.article_id and articles.category_id=categories.category_id) 
where (comments.article_id in(1,2,3,4,5)) 
ORDER BY `comments`.`comment_id`  DESC limit 0 , 5
```

Please focus to `comments_id` and `article_id` columns

- sql-1: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ab6c1/1

[image: result 1]

*As you see;*

- **comments.comment_id desc order** +OK

109

108

107

106

105

**comments.article_id** s +OK

1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5

but **result list shows **2 comments** of every article**

**-I need to "group" articles.article_id s**

so I add **" group by comments.article_id"**

**-SQL-QUERY-2:**

```
select 
comments.comment_id,comments.comment_title,comments.article_id, 
articles.article_id,articles.article_title,articles.category_id, 
categories.category_id,categories.category_name from comments 
left join (articles,categories) on (comments.article_id=articles.article_id and articles.category_id=categories.category_id) 
where (comments.article_id in(1,2,3,4,5)) 
/*for duplicate comments*/ GROUP by comments.article_id /*for duplicate comments*/
ORDER BY `comments`.`comment_id`  DESC limit 0 , 5
```

Please focus to `comments_id` and `article_id` columns

-sql-2: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ab6c1/2

[image: result 2]

it's ok, **comments.article_id s grouped** BUT **"comments.comment_id desc"** order is broken;

108

106

104

102

100

(must be *109 106 104 102 100*)

---

I'm not an expert of mysql(I lost more than 3-4 hours)

---

-I need to show: "**last(desc) 5 comments**" in every category listing pages.

-I need to show: "**last(desc) "1" comment for every article in(1,2,3,4,5 article_id s)**"

---

(distinct and max shows same results 108 106 104 102 100

If I add `group by comments.article_id` and remove `order by comments.comment_id desc`, the list shows FIRST 1 comment of article -- I need to show LAST 1 comment of article)

Can any sql expert help me for this sql query ?

Comment: Why does your data model have two different comments with the same title?

Comment: (i hope i understand what you mean)

- every article unique, every comment unique

I put the sample data to http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ab6c1/1

Comment: Article 1 has two comments with the same title. INSERT INTO `comments` VALUES(100, 1, 'comment_title 1');
INSERT INTO `comments` VALUES(101, 1, 'comment_title 1');

Comment: yes but its sample data :) 
articles, comments, categories table id columns are unique
- some articles has 100+ comments some has 0 and i want to show "LAST 5 commentS of x category" and "ONE LAST comment of x article" comment(if article has comment)

Comment: so, you want to show last 5 comments of 5 specific articles, one comment per article? and what is the connection with categories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to show the last 5 comments of 5 specific articles, one comment per article:

```
select     c.comment_id, c.comment_title, c.article_id, 
           a.article_id, a.article_title, a.category_id, cats.category_name
from       articles      a
inner join categories cats on (a.category_id = cats.category_id)
inner join (select   article_id, max(comment_id) comment_id, comment_title
            from     comments co
            where    co.article_id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
            group by co.article_id) c
            on (a.article_id = c.article_id)
order by    c.comment_id desc
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ab6c1/27

Comment: This is a solution? The OP's accepted it, so I guess it must be.

Comment: -koriander- thank you.

-Strawberry- yes this query shows what i want but really long and complicated for me, i need easy and short way probably i will do this with 2 different query.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help at all...

```
 SELECT x.*
      , COUNT(*) rank
   FROM comments x
   JOIN comments y 
     ON y.article_id = x.article_id
    AND y.comment_id <= x.comment_id
  GROUP
     BY article_id
      , comment_id;
```